# Moving inline event handlers to javascript sheet for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension of a tic tac toe game.  However, my html code has inline event handlers which are not allowed because of the content security.  I need to figure out how to transfer these event handlers to the javascript page.

This is the HTML page, the inline event handlers are in the buttons and they call the function gamestart:

```
  <head>

  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <link href="game.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="singleplayer.js"></script>
  </head>

 <body>
 <center><u><h1>Single Player Mode</h1></u>
 <table> <tr><td>

 <button style="background-color:lightblue ; color: black" id="0" onclick = "gamestart(0)">
 </button></td>
 <td>
 <button style="background-color:lightblue ; color: black" id="1" onclick = "gamestart(1)">    
 </button>

 </td><td>

 <button style="background-color:lightblue ; color: black" id="2" onclick = "gamestart(2)">   
 </button>
 </td></tr>
 <tr><td>
 <button style="background-color:lightblue ; color: black" id="3" onclick = "gamestart(3)">   
 </button>

 </td><td>

 <button style="background-color:lightblue ; color: black" id="4" onclick = "gamestart(4)">   
 </button>

 </td><td>

 <button style="background-color:lightblue ; color: black" id="5" onclick = "gamestart(5)">
 </button>

 </td></tr><tr><td>

 <button style="background-color:lightblue ; color: black" id="6" onclick = "gamestart(6)">
 </button>

 </td><td>

 <button style="background-color:lightblue ; color: black" id="7" onclick = "gamestart(7)">
 </button>

 </td><td>

 <button style="background-color:lightblue ; color: black" id="8" onclick = "gamestart(8)">
 </button>
 </td></tr></table></center>
 </body>
 </html>
```

On the javascript sheet, here is the function that is called using event handlers:

```
var counter=0;
function gamestart(id){
    console.log(id);

    counter=counter+2

    if(counter%1==0){
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "X";
    checkX("X");
    stopbutton("X");    
    setTimeout('player2()',500);
    checktie();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
        gamestart(event.target.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and when a button is clicked, an X appears in the box, but for some reason it just stops there and the second player does not execute.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I figured it out, there was a mistake in part of my code.  You were able to find a simple solution to my problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something in these lines.

Use `addEventListener` to attach the event and target the elements by using `getElementsByTagName` property

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('button'),
    counter = 0;

for(var i=0;i< elem.length;i++) {
    elem[i].addEventListener('click', gamestart);
}

function gamestart(e){
   var id = this.id;
    console.log(id);

    counter=counter+2

    if(counter%1==0){
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "X";
        checkX("X");
        stopbutton("X");    
        setTimeout('player2()',500);
        checktie();
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/GBSX2/)**

Also it's a good practice to separate out your inline styles and place them in a class instead.

```
.highlight {
    background-color:lightblue;
    color: black
}
```

And the `HTML` for the button will look like this

```
 <button class="highlight" id="1">Button 1</button>
```

Nice and clean which only holds the structure of the element and the functionality and styling separated out.

Now you can even target the elements based on the class

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('highlight')
```

Comment: I did everything that you said but for some reason your code works on Fiddle but does nothing happens when I click the button when I actually implemented it.

Comment: Open the developer Tools in chrome by pressing F12 and check for any errors

Comment: There is one error:Uncaught syntax Error: Unexpected end of input (it says it is on the first line)